# Fetch data from APIs without hitting custom function runtime limit (30s)

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, quota

I am looking to fetch data from 2 API endpoints using the ImportJSON script from bradjasper.

From the first API, I'm getting an array of about 100 driver objects (ID, Name). Using the driver ID, I need to poll the second API for additional data (miles, safety score) for each driver. This second API has a rate limit of 5 requests/second.

The problem is that it seems I'm hitting the Apps Script custom function limit of 30 seconds per function. (Error: Exceeded maximum execution time).

What would be the best approach to avoid this 30s limit?

```
function ImportJSONAdvancedDrivers(url, fetchOptions, query, parseOptions, includeFunc, transformFunc) {
  var url = 'https://api.samsara.com/v1/fleet/drivers';
  var includeFunc = includeXPath_;
  var transformFunc = defaultTransform_;
  var fetchOptions = {
       'headers': {
           "Authorization": "XYZ Token",
       },
  }
  var parseOptions = "noInherit, noTruncate";
  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions);
  var object = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText())['drivers'];

  var dateStart = new Date(2023, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0);
  var dateStartMiliseconds = dateStart.getTime();
  var dateEnd = new Date(2023, 1, 1, 1, 59, 59, 0);
  var dateEndMiliseconds = dateEnd.getTime();


  var driversArr = [];
  for (var driver=0; driver < object.length; driver++){
    try {
      var driverId = object[driver].id;
      var driverName = object[driver].name;

      Utilities.sleep(200);

      var driverMilesJson = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.samsara.com/v1/fleet/drivers/" + driverId + "/safety/score?startMs=" + dateStartMiliseconds +"&endMs=" + dateEndMiliseconds, fetchOptions);
      var driverMilesObject = JSON.parse(driverMilesJson.getContentText());
      var driverMeters = driverMilesObject.totalDistanceDrivenMeters;
      var driverMilesRounded = Math.round(driverMeters * 0.00062137 * 100) / 100;
      var driverSafetyScore = driverMilesObject.safetyScore;


      driversArr.push({
        Id: driverId,
        Name: driverName,
        Miles: driverMilesRounded,
        SafetyScore: driverSafetyScore
      }); 
    } catch (error){
        console.error(error);
    }
    

  };


  var object = driversArr;

  return parseJSONObject_(object, query, parseOptions, includeFunc, transformFunc);
}
```

I tried avoiding the 5 requests / second rate limit by using Utilities.sleep(), but then I'm hitting the custom function runtime limit of 30 seconds.

Comment: In your situation, are you required to use your script as a custom function?

Comment: Not necessarily. Is there a better way?

Comment: Thank you for replying. When the custom function is used, the current maximum execution time is 30 seconds. But, for example, when the script is run with the script editor, the custom menu, and a button on the Spreadsheet, the current maximum execution time is 6 minutes. In your situation, how about changing the method for executing the script?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that as a possibility. How should I change it so that it is nut run as a custom function, but with the script editor or custom menu?

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, if your values of `url, fetchOptions, query, parseOptions, includeFunc, transformFunc` are been putting into the cells on Spreadsheet, you can use the values by retrieving them from the cells. And, in this case, it is required to modify the part for putting the values to the Spreadsheet. In your current script, the values are put by `return`. Here, it puts the values using the Spreadsheet service of Google Apps Script. If you want the sample script, please tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if am pointing you in the direction you want, but if you have issues with rate limits and would like to customize your request's timing, you should  consider using a package like [bottleneck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck?activeTab=readme)

Comment: Is it possible to use with Apps Script?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).